# Change the colour and/or width of active cell in spreadsheet in Microsoft Excel in Mac

Tags: excel

In Microsoft Excel(in mac), it becomes very difficult to see the active cell for large spreasheets,

It would be very handy if we can make the active cell with a contrast colour to the table, or increase the width of active cell.

How can we do this? Or atleast, is it possible to increase the font color or boldness of text inside the active cell?

Comment: You can do so with selection change events on the worksheet object.

Comment: @JvdV Describe it

Comment: @AJAY, describing it would require me to put down an answer. OP can search for answers on SO since this is a frequent topic here.